# Pixel 2 & Pixel 2 XL Device Metrics

Tags: android

the material design metrics site doesn't have the metrics for the Pixel 2s (site is found [here](https://material.io/tools/devices/)).

Does anybody happen to know them?

In Android Studio, the Pixel 2 (don't have a pixel 2 xl) reports a smallest width of **485dp** (sw485dp).  Based on our folder structure (sw480dp, sw600dp, sw720dp), this means the pixel 2 gets tablet variables.  I'm going to create a new folder (sw490dp) to catch the pixel 2 but want to get the size of the pixel 2 xl so I can catch that as well (if needed).

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe https://www.phonearena.com/phones/compare/Google-Pixel-2,Google-Pixel-2-XL/phones/10584,10568

Comment: @cricket_007 that just gives pixel dimensions.  The math says it SHOULD be 480dp but it's not